# C++ is quite slower than python in opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, yolo

```
startTime = time.time()
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, float(1.0/255.0), (frameWidth,frameHeight), (0,0,0), swapRB = True, crop = False)
yolo.setInput(blob)
layerOutput = yolo.forward(outputLayers)
endTime = time.time()
```

Python code that I am measuring the time

```
auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
blob = blobFromImage(images[i], 1.0f/255.0f, Size(frameWidth, frameHeight), Scalar(0,0,0), true, false);
net.setInput(blob);
net.forward(layerOutput, getOutputsNames(net));
auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

C++ code that I am measuring time

In C++:

blob is `Mat` type, layerOutput is `vector<Mat>` type, `getOutputsNames` returns in `vector<string>` names.

In python:
blob is `numpy.ndarray` type, `layerOutput` is `tuple` type, `outputLayers` is a `list` type object.

Both backends and targets are the same and backend is opencv, target is cpu, and I am using same yolov4 weight and config files in the same directories

When measuring the time, it takes ~180-200 ms in python, yet in C++ it takes ~220-250 ms. Since C++ is a compiled language, I expect C++ to be work quite fast than the python, which is not the case surprisingly.

What might be the reason that python works faster than the C++? Also what are your solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what optimization level did you use when compiling the C++ code?

Comment: Also, I may be wrong on this, but the core feature of opencv in python may be implemented in C++ since many performance sensitive python packages do so.

Comment: I didn't specified any optimization level, yet I used CMake to compile my code.

Comment: For batch operations in optimized python packages, they all call out to C/C++ code. The python overhead would be tiny and you wouldn't be able to measure it.

Comment: Did you specify CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE as Release (or RelWithDebInfo) when configuring the build ? For future reference, it is the virtual definition of *pointless* to benchmark code without *confirming* it is built with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Yes, I specified it as Release. However, in different directory, I have specified it as debug to use eclipse.

Comment: time.time() measures **wall** time. dont use that for profiling

Comment: Was that intended to clarify the environment, because it didn't. You basically said you built two different configurations (Release and Debug), but made no mention about **which** was being profiled. Care to try again?

Comment: Any suggestions in the python then?

Comment: I am profiling the release version of course.

Comment: Wonderful. That info belongs in the question above, and we can wipe this entire comment chain. Maybe also include the full cmdline cmake config, build, and execution displaying measurement for C++, and likewise for Python if available.

Comment: Can you expand it further please?

Comment: FYI when you solve your own problem, the solution should be posted as an *answer*, not as an *edit* to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the problem is, I have customized OpenCV for c++ to gain advantage of the CUDA cores in my Jetson Orin, yet the python uses general OpenCV stored in other directory, which doesn't have CUDA support. When I changed the OpenCV compilation for C++ to the general one, it worked fast as expected since in my customized compilation I also customized the CPU parallelization which seems to be slower than the default one.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, it's not like that. `python-opencv` module is mostly written in C++ and C. The compiled code is then used by python using some kind of binding maybe. For example, I wrote an image registration code in C++ and used pybind to call the binary (.so file) from python. So if it works faster, it's not just Python.
Now come to your question. It can have multiple reasons why your python code works faster than C++.

1. As in the comment, some people mentioned that it can be because of optimized binaries used by the Opencv module for Python.
2. Check the CPU utilization and number of threads while running the both code.
3. It can be a data structure and algorithm which is causing the speed. Example, you are using `Mat` to read the image in C++ while for Python you are using `Numpy` which have it's core written in C which is faster than C++.